# Is it possible to define the adress of a function in assembly?

Tags: disassembly, anti-debugging, disassemblers, compilers

I am creating a PoC for anti-disassembly techniques, and I would like to know if there were ways to define the address of functions once compiled with gcc.

Here is the PoC program :

```
BITS 32
EXTERN puts
SECTION .data
    chaine      db "Hello world !", 0

SECTION .text
    GLOBAL main

    I_Want_to_control_this_func_addr:
    ret

    main:
    push chaine
    ; xor eax, eax
   jz beer+1
beer:
   db 0xe8
    add al, 3
    add al, 8
    pop eax
    ret
```

I would like the function to have the address `0x08040309`.

I am compiling with : `nasm -f elf test.asm; gcc -m32 -o test test.o`